# python stacking lines in terminal

Tags: python

Python does not continue to replace the same line in the terminal, but it replaces "name" and adds the progress bar to a new line which results in a huge stack of progress bars...this only happens when I use "\n" before "name". How can I get the result to look like this?

```
[###                                                               ] 4%
name2
```

python

```
mylist = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3',...'name66']

for name in mylist:
  sys.stdout.write('\r[%-66s] %d%%' % ('#'*prog, (prog*1.51515151515))+'\n'+name)
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: That's what `\n` does. What's your question?

Comment: yeah, I really don't understand your question. What does it look like now?

Comment: Wow im an idiot, what i want is for "name" to wrap to the next line without the prograssbar stacking

Comment: Without a lot of gymnastics (e.g. using [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)) you can't. Don't write `\n` if you want to keep updating the current line.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2) for this. It works well and is easy to configure in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using enough blank spaces too look like a new line, but not actually use the newline character. Then use the backspace character `\b` to move your cursor back to the beginning of the line and overwrite all that you wrote.

I extended your example a bit to make it a runnable script, by throwing a sleep in there and manually incrementing `prog`.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import os

# Get the number of columns in the terminal
rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
columns = int(columns)

mylist = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3','name4']
prog = 0
for name in mylist:
    prog += 10
    bar = '[%-66s] %d%%' % ('#'*prog, (prog*1.51515151515))
    spaces_left = columns-len(bar)
    sys.stdout.write(bar+(" "*spaces_left)+name+('\b'*(len(name) + columns)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(.5)
```